# MongoDB does not create database nor user from Docker compose file

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

The three files are involved in this case:

```
/mongo/init/init-mongo.js
.env.development
docker-compose.yml
```

The problem: when Mongo instance is up, it is empty. No users, no databases, no collections.

I can connect to containers' `mongosh` utility: `docker exec -it ord-data-backend-db mongosh` and execute `show databases` and it is empty! But `/bin/bash` there receives environment variables defined in **docker-compose.yml** file.

The Mongo instance is empty, hence frontend container could not start because health check fails.

**docker-compose.yml** itself:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo:6.0
    container_name: ord-data-backend-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '${MONGO_PORT}:27017'
    healthcheck:
      test:  echo 'db.runCommand('ping').ok' | mongosh localhost:${MONGO_PORT}/test --quiet
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 10s
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${MONGO_DB_NAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_USER: ${MONGO_DB_ADMIN_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_DB_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./mongo/db:/data/db
      - ./mongo/initdb.d/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express:0.54.0
    container_name: ord-data-backend-db-front
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: ${ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME}
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: ${ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD}
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN: true
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: ${MONGO_DB_ADMIN_USERNAME}
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_DB_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT: ${MONGO_PORT}
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SSL: false
    depends_on:
      mongo:
        condition: service_healthy
```

**.env.development**:

```
MONGO_PORT=27018
MONGO_DB_NAME=ord-data-backend
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=p@$$w0rd
MONGO_DB_ADMIN_USERNAME=kw
MONGO_DB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=p@$$w0rd
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=p@$$w0rd
```

And **init-mongo.js**:

```js
db = db.getSiblingDB(process.env.MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE);
db.createUser({
  user: process.env.MONGO_INITDB_USER,
  pwd: process.env.MONGO_INITDB_PASSWORD,
  roles: [
    {
      role: 'readWrite',
      db: process.env.MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE,
    },
  ],
});
db.createCollection('data');
```

To launch it, I use `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml --env-file .env.development up -d` command.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. As I mentioned, there is nothing wrong with any of this setup.

I restarted Windows and it has been fixed. I guess there was a problem with Windows' network stack.